# Regarding predicate logic and universal quantifiers,

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

What is the difference between
$$
\forall x \in X (P(x) \iff \exists y \in X \ (D(x,y)))
$$

and

$$
\forall x \in X, \exists y \in X , (P(x) \iff D(x,y))
$$

I'm a bit confused, wouldn't they end up meaning the same thing once you expand it out? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: In the first sentence, the existence of $y$ is conditioned on $P$(x). In the second sentence, $y$ exists for sure, and only $D(x,y)$ is interdependent with $P(x)$.

Comment: Could you give an example that would make one statement true and the other false?

Answer (score 0):

If they are equivalent then, comparing the formulas after the first quantification we must have
$$
(P(x) \leftrightarrow\exists y \in X \ : \,D(x,y)) \iff \exists y \in X : (P(x) \leftrightarrow D(x,y))
$$
the last equivalence you can check [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(P(x)%E2%86%94%E2%88%83yD(x,y))%E2%86%94(%E2%88%83y(P(x)%E2%86%94D(x,y)))) that t is false.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please explain?

Comment: Can you explain this in simpler terms? We have not covered this in class. From my understanding the first statement is saying, 

"for all x in X, P(x) is true if and only if for all x in X there exists a y in X where D(x,y) is true"

whereas the second one is saying: 

"for all x in X, there exists a y in X where P(x) is true if and only if D(x,y) is true"

Comment: Have you learned anything called *prenex normal form* ?

Comment: Nope. Did the sentences I make make sense, or were they incorrect?

Comment: You have to bring the two statements into the prenex normal form, i.e., quantifiers stands on the left only, then compare the *matrix* i.e., the statements after the quantifiers

Comment: It is too late  here, I'll continue this question tommorrow